# docker-compose error when deploying portainer

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I was deploying django with Portainer.

While deploying, the following error occurred in django image log.

**django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration account.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.**

I deleted the migrations file and tried to migrate again and deploy, but the same error occurred.

maybe I think the problem is probably caused by customizing the User model.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you reset/delete the database to start fresh? If the migration is already applied then you need to unapply it. `docker-compose down -v` will delete any volumes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not simply delete your migration files like that because the migration state is stored in your database, not only just in your migration files.

Open your database and check your django_migrations table and you will understand where your error come from. The error message means that Django find out the migration `account.0001_initial` existed on django_migrations table without `users.0001_initial`, but your migration files defined that `users.0001_initial` has to be before the `account.0001_initial`. So it don't know how to process the confliction.

If your data is not important, simply drop your database and create a new one will help. Secondly, you will have to follow the process to reverse a migration instead of deleting it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations

I recommend you to read the whole https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/.

Comment: Thanks about your answer.
but i think that's not solution.
that's why now im deploying new server...
sry but it does big help!

Comment: i solved this problem!
i just create new DB on portainer volume.. thanks!